# Attaching angularjs controller via directive is not assigning class="ng-scope"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular so apologies if I am missing a simple concept here.  I have developed my application using a lot of directives to put in sections of my site.  They have a template and a controller and I am assigning the controller inside of the direct.  I intend to use these bits on other places on the site

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <ng-blah-logo></ng-blah-logo>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ng-blah-login></ng-blah-login>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<ng-blah-marketplace-form></ng-blah-marketplace-form>
```

The JS is (what I thought was) pretty straight forward:

```
var ngBlahMarketplaceFormCtrl = function($scope) {
    console.log($scope)

    $scope.form.name = ''
    $scope.form.phone = ''
    $scope.form.firm = ''
    $scope.form.brief = ''


    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log('ngBlahMarketPlaceFormCtrl::submit()')
        console.log($scope.form)
    }
}

app.directive('ngBlahMarketplaceForm', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: true
        , replace: true
        , templateUrl: '/resources/ngViews/marketplaceForm.html'
        , controller: 'ngBlahMarketplaceFormCtrl'
    };
});

var ngBlahLoginCtrl = function($scope) {
    console.log($scope)

    $scope.default = {}
    $scope.default.username = 'username' ;
    $scope.default.password = 'password';

    $scope.form = _.clone($scope.default) ;

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log('ngBlahLoginCtrl::submit()')
    }
    $scope.help = function() {
        console.log('ngBlahLoginCtrl::help()')
    }
}


// login form and the controller to logic
app.directive('ngBlahLogin', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: true
        , replace: true
        , controller: 'ngBlahLoginCtrl'
        , templateUrl: '/resources/ngViews/loginThin.html'

    };
});
```

OK so the issue I have is that only one scope is being created.  When I investigate the DOM the only element with a class="ng-scope" is the Body tag.  What have I done to get this behavior?  Do I need to post more code to assist in getting to the bottom of this?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5UxX/
Inside of the JS Fiddle you can see two logs to the console inside of two different controller.  Both times it logs the scope variable, and in both cases the scope.id are the same

Edit: clarifying the problem, which is that my two controllers share the same $scope variable.  The page "renders" (the HTML) as expected.  For some reason the only element with a class="ng-scpoe" attribute is the body tag (which contains the ng-app attribute as well).

Thanks again

Comment: please post Fiddle or Plunker to help us to detect the issue. Thanks

Comment: fiddle it is: http://jsfiddle.net/U5UxX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working example based on your code.

added to directive `scope:true`

`scope:true` will create a child scope that will "prototypically" inherit from its parent, so you will be able to access values defined on parent's scope in your directive.

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

fessmodule.controller('ngMarketplaceFormCtrl', function($scope) {
console.log($scope)

$scope.name = ''
$scope.phone = ''
$scope.firm = ''
$scope.brief = ''


 $scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('ngMarketPlaceFormCtrl::submit()')
    console.log($scope.form)
 }
});

fessmodule.directive('ngMarketplaceForm', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ngMarketplaceFormCtrl',
    template: '<div class="well marketplaceWell">\
                        <div style="margin-left: 15px">\
                            <div class="form-group row">Start a RFP</div>\
                            <div class="form-group row"><input type="text" placeholder="name" class="col-md-9" ng-model="name"/></div>\
                            <div class="form-group row"><input type="text" placeholder="firm" class="col-md-9" ng-model="firm"/></div>\
                            <div class="form-group row"><input type="text" placeholder="phone number" class="col-md-9" ng-model="phone"/></div>\
                            <div class="form-group row"><textarea type="text" placeholder="proposal brief" class="col-md-9" ng-model="brief"></textarea>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="form-group row">\
                                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>'
   };
});


fessmodule.controller('ngLoginCtrl', function($scope) {
console.log($scope)

$scope.
default = {}
$scope.
default.username = 'username';
$scope.
default.password = 'password';

$scope.form = _.clone($scope.
default);

$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('ngLoginCtrl::submit()')
}
$scope.help = function () {
    console.log('ngLoginCtrl::help()')
 }
});


// login form and the controller to logic
fessmodule.directive('ngLogin', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ngLoginCtrl',
    template: '<div class="pull-left">\
                        <div class="login-form">\
                            <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="form.username" no-ng-dodilio-smart-default />\
                            <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="form.password" no-ng-dodilio-smart-default />\
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">SIGN IN</button>\
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="help()">?</button>\
                        </div >\
                    </div>'

   };
});
```

console:

```
a {$id: "003", this: a, $$listeners: Object, $parent: e, $$childTail: null…}
a {$id: "004", this: a, $$listeners: Object, $parent: e, $$childTail: null…}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/523/)</kbd>

Hope it will help you,

Comment: I dont think it works, at least it doesn't in my browser.  If you examine the two $scope variables being output by the console.log, you will see they share the same object ID.  this isn't correct, at least I don't believe it to be...

Comment: I found your problem, scope: true

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer (even after reading the directive page on angularJs), but it does work. So I am going to mark it correct, and continue on reading about the solution...  Thanks